# where is my Worklight Console?

Tags: eclipse, xampp, ibm-mobilefirst

I've installed IBM Worklight Studio in Eclipse, and everything was going well until I decided  to install XAMPP software to get Apache PHP. Then I loaded Worklight Console, but the page said "Chrome has not been able to establish connection with the page".

I'm freaked out and uninstalled XAMPP although the problem persists.

Comment: Has your question been answered?

Answer (score 1):

Is this the actual error message you see in Chrome?
I googled it and there does not seem to be such an error message.

Make sure your Worklight Server is up and running. Also make sure there is nothing left of XAMPP, as it sounds like something is still blocking port 8080, which Worklight requires by default when using the Developer Edition (the Eclipse Studio plug-in).

Also try clearing your browser cache just in case.